# Find the measure of set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $ A = \{(x, y) \in R ^ 2: x^2 + y ^ 2 \le 1, 1 - | x | \le y\} $. Find the measure of set A and calculate the integrals

(a) $ \int_ {A} (xy + 2) d \lambda_2 (x, y)$;

(b) $ \int_ {A} y \quad d \lambda_2 (x, y) $;

Please help, I am trying to find the harvest measure first and I am not sure that I am doing it right:

I found what such a field looks like (i.e. the intersection of two sets), I got that it is a circle with a radius of 1 (center in (0, 0))
with a cut triangle with a base 2, height 1,

So the measure is: $ \frac{1}{2} \cdot (\pi - 2) $?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The green area is the measure you need to find out which is $\frac{1}{2}(\pi-2).$ For the part (a) and (b), you need to evaluate double limits as follows.

(a) $\underset{A}{\int}(xy+2)d\lambda_2(x,y)=\overset{1}{\underset{x=0}{\int}} \overset{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\underset{y=1-x}{\int}}(xy+2)dxdy + \overset{0}{\underset{x=-1}{\int}} \overset{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\underset{y=1+x}{\int}}(xy+2)dxdy; $

(b) $\underset{A}{\int}yd\lambda_2(x,y)=\overset{1}{\underset{x=0}{\int}} \overset{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\underset{y=1-x}{\int}} ydxdy + \overset{0}{\underset{x=-1}{\int}} \overset{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\underset{y=1+x}{\int}}  ydxdy. $